# Show Page # of Section - not "absolute" page number

Tags: microsoft-word

Is there a way to have a footer show the current page number *within a section*?

Let's say I have three sections. Each section is 10 pages. I would like my footers to show "Page 1 of 10" for each section.

Currently, I just have `{ PAGE \* MERGEFORMAT } of { SECTIONPAGES \* MERGEFORMAT }`

This, of course, works great for the first section. However, the second section footer starts `Page 11 of 10`...I want it to say `Page 1 of 10`.

Is there something like `SectionPage`?

The one workaround I know of is to go to the start of each section, and reset the footer number to Start at 1. If that's the solution, then fine, I'll do that - I was just curious if/why Word has a built in "Section Page", because they have "SectionPages", so where's "SectionPage"?

Thanks for any ideas!

(Word 2010 and 2016)

Comment: "If that's the solution," Yes, it is.

Comment: @DavidPostill - There's no way to do `SectionPage`? That's a pretty obvious feature I'd think MS would have realized, and added.  Or is there logic to instead manually setting page starts, instead of having such a feature?

Comment: @BruceWayne: since there is no SectionPage, you can either try to ensure that you put something like a bookmark or SEQ field at the end of each section and reference that (but they are so easy to delete by accident), or try to use fields in the header, e.g. : { SET PPP0 0 }{ SET "PPP{ SECTION }" { PAGE }, then  { ={ PAGE }-{ REF "PPP{ ={ SECTION }-1 }" } } for page within section (various assumptions e.g. continuous page numbering, single-sided, probably no continuous section breaks). But it never quite works, and double-sided documents introduce extra problems.

Comment: @bibadia - Thanks for your comment!  I've been looking still and can't find anything.  I suppose I'll just set the start of each section manually.  Thanks for your tips though, I think that would work, but it would be more complicated to explain to others (and this is a 100+ page double sided document).  Cheers!